# navXT breadcrumbs plugin for wordpress, hide post title

Tags: wordpress, plugins, breadcrumbs

i'm trying to hide the post titles using this plugin http://mtekk.weblogs.us/code/breadcrumb-navxt/ so i want to show the full breadcrumbs always, except when entering to a post, in there, i just wanna hide the post's title, i find it's code kind'a confusing, i managed to hide the "current page title" but not the "post title" only specifically... anybody with any experience on this?...

Answer (score 1):

In the admin section of the plugin, try setting the prefix option as "`<span style="display:none">`" and suffix option as "`</span>`" on whatever section your trying to hide.
The end of your explanation left me a bit fuzzy, but....